# Unchecking checkboxes after PDF and before restarting loop

Tags: excel, vba

My code below, populates the report in "Design" tab with each record in the "Claims" tab, which also includes checking a few boxes. The report is then printed to pdf and then looped for each record in Claims tab. However, the checkboxes stay checked based on the first records and doesn't get unchecked at the end of the loop. Any help on vba that would uncheck all boxes after printing to pdf would be appreciated.

```
Sub ExportingPDF()

Dim claimsSheet As Worksheet
Dim reportSheet As Worksheet

Set reportSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("design")
Set claimsSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("claims")

'Looping through each row'
With reportSheet

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

For i = 2 To lastRow

'Generating Output - Pinpointing Claims Data'
SOrganization = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 1)
SMRN = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 2)
SPatient_Name = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 3)
SDOS = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 4)
SBilling_Provider = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 5)
SBilled_CPT = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 8)
SBilled_Modifier = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 9)
SAudit_Program = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 10)
SAuditors_Initials = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 11)
SAudit_Date = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 12)
SAudit_CPT = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 13)
SAudit_Modifier = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 14)
SError_Category = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 15)
SOther_Error = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 16)
SChief_Complaint = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 17)
SMedically_Appropriate_History = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 18)
SMedically_Appropriate_Exam = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 19)
STime_Documented = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 21)
SOther = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 22)
SProblem_Notes = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 25)
SData_Notes = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 30)
SRisk_Notes = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 33)
  
'Generating Output - Pintpointing Location in Report'
reportSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = SOrganization
reportSheet.Cells(2, 3).Value = SMRN
reportSheet.Cells(3, 3).Value = SPatient_Name
reportSheet.Cells(4, 3).Value = SDOS
reportSheet.Cells(5, 3).Value = SBilling_Provider
reportSheet.Cells(6, 3).Value = SBilled_CPT
reportSheet.Cells(7, 3).Value = SBilled_Modifier
reportSheet.Cells(1, 7).Value = SAudit_Program
reportSheet.Cells(2, 7).Value = SAuditors_Initials
reportSheet.Cells(3, 7).Value = SAudit_Date
reportSheet.Cells(4, 7).Value = SError_Category
reportSheet.Cells(5, 7).Value = SOther_Error
reportSheet.Cells(6, 7).Value = SAudit_CPT
reportSheet.Cells(7, 7).Value = SAudit_Modifier
reportSheet.Cells(1, 10).Value = SChief_Complaint
reportSheet.Cells(2, 10).Value = SMedically_Appropriate_History
reportSheet.Cells(3, 10).Value = SMedically_Appropriate_Exam
reportSheet.Cells(53, 8).Value = STime_Documented
reportSheet.Cells(53, 10).Value = SOther
reportSheet.Cells(48, 2).Value = SProblem_Notes
reportSheet.Cells(48, 4).Value = SData_Notes
reportSheet.Cells(48, 9).Value = SRisk_Notes

Sheets("design").CheckBox1.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("x2") = "1 self-limited or minor problem"
Sheets("design").CheckBox2.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("x2") = "2 or more self limited or minor problems"
Sheets("design").CheckBox3.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("x2") = "1 stable, chronic illness"
Sheets("design").CheckBox4.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("x2") = "1 acute, uncomplicated illness or injury"
Sheets("design").CheckBox5.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("x2") = "1 stable, acute illness"
Sheets("design").CheckBox6.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("x2") = "1 acute, uncomplicated illness or injury requiring hospital IP or OBS level of care"
Sheets("design").CheckBox7.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("x2") = "1 or more chronic illnesses with exacerbation, progression, or side effects of treatment"
Sheets("design").CheckBox8.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("x2") = "2 or more stable, chronic illnesses"
Sheets("design").CheckBox9.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("x2") = "1 undiagnosed new problem with uncertain prognosis"
Sheets("design").CheckBox10.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("x2") = "1 acute illness with systemic systems"
Sheets("design").CheckBox11.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("x2") = "1 acute, complicated injury"
Sheets("design").CheckBox12.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("x2") = "1 or more chronic illnesses with severe exacerbation, progression, or side effects of treatment;"
Sheets("design").CheckBox13.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("x2") = "1 acute or chronic illness or injury that poses a threat to life or bodily function"

Sheets("design").CheckBox14.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "Category 1 tests and documents"
Sheets("design").CheckBox15.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "Review of prior external note(s) from each unique source"
Sheets("design").CheckBox16.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "review of result(s) of each unique test*"
Sheets("design").CheckBox17.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "ordering of each unique test"
Sheets("design").CheckBox18.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "Category 2: Assessment requiring an independent historian(s)"
Sheets("design").CheckBox19.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("AB2") = "Review of prior external note(s) from each unique source"
Sheets("design").CheckBox20.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("AB2") = "review of result(s) of each unique test*"
Sheets("design").CheckBox21.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("AB2") = "ordering of each unique test"

Sheets("design").CheckBox22.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "Category 1: Tests, documents, or independent historian(s)"
Sheets("design").CheckBox23.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "Review of prior external note(s) from each unique souce*"
Sheets("design").CheckBox24.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "Review of the result(s) of each unique test"
Sheets("design").CheckBox25.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "Ordering of each unique test*"
Sheets("design").CheckBox67.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "Assessment requiring an independent historian(s)"
Sheets("design").CheckBox33.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "Category 2: Independent Interpretation of Tests performed by another physician/other QHP"
Sheets("design").CheckBox34.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "Catergory 3: discussion of management or test interpretation with external physician/other QHP/appropriate source"
Sheets("design").CheckBox26.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("ab2") = "Review of prior external note(s) from each unique souce*"
Sheets("design").CheckBox27.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("ab2") = "Review of the result(s) of each unique test"
Sheets("design").CheckBox28.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("ab2") = "Ordering of each unique test*"
Sheets("design").CheckBox29.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("ac2") = "Review of prior external note(s) from each unique souce*"
Sheets("design").CheckBox30.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("ac2") = "Review of the result(s) of each unique test"
Sheets("design").CheckBox31.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("ac2") = "Ordering of each unique test*"

Sheets("design").CheckBox35.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "Category 1: tests, documents, or independent historian(s)"
Sheets("design").CheckBox36.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "review of prior external note(s) from each unique source"
Sheets("design").CheckBox39.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "review of the result(s) of each unique test"
Sheets("design").CheckBox42.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "ordering of each unique test"
Sheets("design").CheckBox45.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "Assessment requiring an independent historian(s)"
Sheets("design").CheckBox46.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "Category 2: Independent interpretation of tests "
Sheets("design").CheckBox47.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("aa2") = "Category 3: Discussion of management or test interpretation with external physician/other qualified health care professional/appropriate source (not separately reported)"
Sheets("design").CheckBox37.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("ab2") = "review of prior external note(s) from each unique source"
Sheets("design").CheckBox40.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("ab2") = "review of the result(s) of each unique test"
Sheets("design").CheckBox43.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("ab2") = "ordering of each unique test"
Sheets("design").CheckBox38.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("ac2") = "review of prior external note(s) from each unique source"
Sheets("design").CheckBox41.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("ac2") = "review of the result(s) of each unique test"
Sheets("design").CheckBox44.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("ac2") = "ordering of each unique test"

Sheets("design").CheckBox48.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "Follow up"
Sheets("design").CheckBox49.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "Rest"
Sheets("design").CheckBox50.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "Gargles"
Sheets("design").CheckBox51.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "Superficial Dressings"
Sheets("design").CheckBox52.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "Minor Surgery w/o identified risk factors"
Sheets("design").CheckBox53.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "physical/occupational therapy"
Sheets("design").CheckBox54.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "iv fluids w/o additives"
Sheets("design").CheckBox55.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "over the counter medication management"
Sheets("design").CheckBox56.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "DME"
Sheets("design").CheckBox57.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "Consult/referral without elaboration"
Sheets("design").CheckBox32.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "Prescription drug management"
Sheets("design").CheckBox58.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "Decision regarding minor surgery with identified patient or procedure risk factors"
Sheets("design").CheckBox59.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "Decision regarding elective major surgery w/o identified patient or procedure risk factors"
Sheets("design").CheckBox60.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "Diagnoses or treatment significantly limited by social determinants of health"
Sheets("design").CheckBox61.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "Drug therapy requiring intensive monitoring for toxicity"
Sheets("design").CheckBox62.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "Decision regarding elective major surgery with identified patient or procedure risk factors"
Sheets("design").CheckBox63.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "Decision regarding emergency major surgery"
Sheets("design").CheckBox64.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "Decision regarding hospitalization or escalation of hospital level care"
Sheets("design").CheckBox65.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "Decision not to resuscitate or to deescalate care because of poor prognosis"
Sheets("design").CheckBox66.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("Af2") = "Parental care substances"
Sheets("design").CheckBox68.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("T2") = "Yes"


'Save the PDF'
reportSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\ortegar\Pictures\" & SMRN, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False


Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a suggestion but all that checkbox configuration could be driven from a table on a worksheet.  3 columns with (eg) `X2 | 1 self-limited or minor problem | CheckBox1`, `X2 | 2 or more self limited or minor problems | CheckBox2` would shorten your code and make it more maintainable.

Comment: Thank you! I new to this so I will keep that in mind! At this point I am just trying to roll this automated report out lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions below (and a fix for the current problem).

I added a new worksheet "config" to hold the information about which checkboxes get set based on the info in the source row:

[image]

The information there was pulled out of your checkbox VBA.  The code loops over that information to check/uncheck checkboxes as needed.  It's more compact and easier to maintain I think.

```
Sub ExportingPDF()

    Dim claimsSheet As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
    Dim reportSheet As Worksheet, res As Boolean, rw As Range
    Dim configSheet As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, arr, r As Long, lrConfig As Long
    
    Set reportSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("design")
    Set claimsSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("claims")
    Set configSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("config") 'this sheet has the checkbox setup table
    
    lrConfig = configSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arr = configSheet.Range("A2:C" & lrConfig).Value
    
    lastRow = claimsSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRow             'Loop each row
        Set rw = claimsSheet.Rows(i) 'using this to reduce code bulk
        reportSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = rw.Cells(1) 'SOrganization
        reportSheet.Cells(2, 3).Value = rw.Cells(2) 'SMRN
        reportSheet.Cells(3, 3).Value = rw.Cells(3) 'SPatient_Name
        reportSheet.Cells(4, 3).Value = rw.Cells(4) 'SDOS
        reportSheet.Cells(5, 3).Value = rw.Cells(5) 'SBilling_Provider
        reportSheet.Cells(6, 3).Value = rw.Cells(8) 'SBilled_CPT
        reportSheet.Cells(7, 3).Value = rw.Cells(9) 'SBilled_Modifier
        reportSheet.Cells(1, 7).Value = rw.Cells(10) 'SAudit_Program
        reportSheet.Cells(2, 7).Value = rw.Cells(11) 'SAuditors_Initials
        reportSheet.Cells(3, 7).Value = rw.Cells(12) 'SAudit_Date
        reportSheet.Cells(4, 7).Value = rw.Cells(15) 'SError_Category
        reportSheet.Cells(5, 7).Value = rw.Cells(16) 'SOther_Error
        reportSheet.Cells(6, 7).Value = rw.Cells(13) 'SAudit_CPT
        reportSheet.Cells(7, 7).Value = rw.Cells(14) 'SAudit_Modifier
        reportSheet.Cells(1, 10).Value = rw.Cells(17) 'SChief_Complaint
        reportSheet.Cells(2, 10).Value = rw.Cells(18) 'SMedically_Appropriate_History
        reportSheet.Cells(3, 10).Value = rw.Cells(19) 'SMedically_Appropriate_Exam
        reportSheet.Cells(53, 8).Value = rw.Cells(21) 'STime_Documented
        reportSheet.Cells(53, 10).Value = rw.Cells(22) 'SOther
        reportSheet.Cells(48, 2).Value = rw.Cells(25) 'SProblem_Notes
        reportSheet.Cells(48, 4).Value = rw.Cells(30) 'SData_Notes
        reportSheet.Cells(48, 9).Value = rw.Cells(33) 'SRisk_Notes
        
        'run through the checkbox configuration info and check/uncheck as appropriate
        'arr(r,1) = checkbox name
        'arr(r,2) = source column letter on current row
        'arr(r,3) = the text to compare
        For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            res = (rw.Columns(arr(r, 2)).Value = arr(r, 3))      'compare values
            reportSheet.OLEObjects(arr(r, 1)).Object.Value = res 'check/uncheck
        Next r
        
        'Save the PDF'
        reportSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Users\ortegar\Documents\" _
            & SMRN, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
    
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! The code appears correct but for some reason the checks dont change. Maybe the issue is elsewhere. Do you think my Checkbox VBA above is static and only referencing the original cells or should that not matter?

Comment: You are using ActiveX checkboxes, correct?  Do you see any output in the Immediate pane from the edited code above?

Comment: Yes I am. So i inserted the code without the sub and end sub after the print pdf code. After running, both all reports (2 rows worth) print but keep the checks from the first record. In my design sheet, the checks stay as well instead of unchecking. No errors or messages appear.    When I run the code alone, it does uncheck everything

Comment: Made a couple edits above to put the checkbox code into a sub which can be called from your main code.  If that doesn't work then likely I can't explain why without seeing the workbook.

Comment: i did exactly what you said and I its not working. weird because your previous code worked fine when ran alone. This code when ran, prompts me to select my main code to run, when I do, i get the same wrong outcome.

Comment: A sub with a parameter can't be run directly - you need to call it from another sub.  Are you able to share your workbook (suitably redacted) ?

Comment: Can I share the book through here?

Comment: https://file.io/o90SKpSEc8Y9 file is available there and will expire soon.

Comment: I see the issue - for example `Sheets("claims").Range("x2") = "1 self-limited or minor problem"` is only looking at row 2 on the input sheet.  `Sheets("claims").Cells(i, "x") = "1 self-limited or minor problem"` should fix that.

Comment: i accepted your code above. Although I only tried your comment from yesterday which is what worked for me.

Comment: OK - thanks.  You might consider making some changes to make your code more robust - I think needing all of those strings to be an exact match for the checkboxes to work correctly might be a slight liability, since you need to coordinate any changes across multiple places.  Ideally you'd find some way to link the checkboxes and selected values on your LevelCategory sheet, so each string only exists in one place.

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried giving you code a try and its not looping nor checking boxes. I created the config table as you explained but no luck. I get document not saved error at the end which i always got but this time a pdf isnt being created and values on the first row of data in claims sheet are showing in the design tab

Comment: update: now i am getting a define object error on res = (rw.Columns(arr(r, 2)).Value = arr(r, 3))

Comment: Please ignore I found a work around

Comment: I can send you a link to my copy if you're still having problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a loop that uncheck all the boxes when you are done printing your PDF:

```vb
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    For Each cb In Sheets("design").CheckBoxes
        cb.Value = xlOff
    Next cb
```

Comment: thanks you but it doesnt seem to be working. The second printed report, contains the same checks as the first report, which should be the case.

Comment: one of the errors I sometime get is "Unable to set the property of checkbox class" with highlight on "cb.Value = xlOff"